# Cant delete or send data to php

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I cant send the ID to PHP to delete the row and i get this error

> TypeError: 'checkValidity' called on an object that does not implement
>   interface HTMLButtonElement.

if I do this **script**

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".del_beneficiaries",function(){
            var id = jQuery(this);
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "ben_del.php",
                data: {
                    "id" : id
                }
            });
        });
```

but if do this **script** their is no data send into my PHP

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".del_beneficiaries",function(){
            var id = [];
            jQuery(".beneficiaries_rows").each(function(){
                var rows = jQuery(this).attr("data-id");
                id.push(rows);
            });
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "ben_del.php",
                data: {
                    "id" : id
                }
            });
        });
```

also if i make this **script** still no data send into PHP

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".del_beneficiaries",function(){
            var id = [];
            jQuery(".data-id").each(function(){
                var rows = jQuery(this).closest(".beneficiaries_rows");
                id.push(rows);
            });
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "ben_del.php",
                data: {
                    "id" : id
                }
            });
        });
```

this is the **HTML**

```
<table style="border: 2px solid black;margin:auto;">
    <tr>
        <th width="100%"><center>Name<center></th>
        <th><center>Action</center></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
        echo "<tr class='beneficiaries_rows' id='".$row1['id']."' value='".$row1['ben_id']."'>";
        echo "<td>".$row1['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<center><button class='del_beneficiaries'>X</button><center>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: you are pushing jQuery objects into array to send as data. That breaks when jQuery tries to serialize them. What exactly are you wanting to send? The selector you have doesn't match anything in the html

Comment: @charlietfl im sending the ben_id to my php to delete the data in it which is name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer i need to call the row first and give it an `ben_id`(primary key) just like this

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".del_beneficiaries",function(){
            var row = jQuery(this).closest(".beneficiaries_rows"); //call the rows
            var id = row.attr("data-id"); //give the rows the specific ben_id
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "ben_del.php",
                data: {
                    "id" : id
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to tr element by its class and then retrieve the id. I recommend you to read jquery documentation [http://api.jquery.com/].
Also, you can use $ instead JQuery in your code.
Maybe this is a homework, and I can't give you the complete solution.

Hint: $('.class').attr(...

Comment: im using jquery ui

Comment: but my html is correct? just the script should i change?

Comment: the link you give is **not found**

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/
Also, I recommend you, to put the 'id' as a custom attribute in your button tag, this way you can access to it in a easiest way.

Comment: if i make it an `id` does it loop?

Comment: put your hands on and see what happen ;)

Comment: I already got the answer sir and i post it here bdw thank you for the tip

Answer (score 1):

You are using JQuery's click event to different class(del_beneficiaries) and your delete ID is stored in different class (beneficiaries_rows). I used your HTML with static data and your First JS Script to get ID to delete rows.

Your HTML :

```
<table style="border: 2px solid black;margin:auto;">
<tr>
    <th width="100%"><center>Name<center></th>
    <th><center>Action</center></th>
</tr>
<?php
    //while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    echo "<tr class='beneficiaries_rows' id='1' value='22'>";
    echo "<td>".'Ravi'."</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<center><button class='del_beneficiaries'>X</button><center>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    //}
?>
```

Your Script :

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).on("click",".del_beneficiaries",function(){
        var id = jQuery('#1').attr('value'); 
        alert(id);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "ben_del.php",
            data: {
                "id" : id
            }
        });
    });
```